Which Azure service to use to restrict the use of Static Web app to particular IP address and attach domain?
I want to attach domain to my Static Web app
and restrict its use to a particular IP address range.
I believe the above cannot be achieved by Azure Static web app itself.
Application Gateway or Front Door can help in this.
Which service should I use keeping cost in mind, and in future if I might want to add more security related restrictions?
Thanks


Which Azure service to use to restrict the use of Static Web app to particular IP address and attach domain?

You can use  Pricing Calculator to check the cost of each service and select the best one as per requirement.
The Azure Front Door will provide more secure features and fulfill all your requirements, such as blocking IPs and adding a custom domain
You can add the domain to your Front Door profile by following the MS Doc.

To block traffic from a specific IP address range, you can create a WAF policy. Follow this MS Doc for more details.


